# SSIS - OData Connection Manager Editor Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odata

I was using OData source to load data from SharePoint 2013 List to SQL Server and the same was working for months. Now I am receiving below error in OData Source connection manager. SharePoint server is UP and I am able to access it from browser using the same credentials. Please help

[Image shows the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emlpW.jpg)

Error Information:

***The partner returned a bad sign-in name or password error. For more information, see Federation Error-handling Scenarios. (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.ODataConnectionManager)***

Comment: What method are you using to ensure that the credentials are the same between your test and the ssis package? Also, your SharePoint admin should see the bad sign in in their logs with a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you Ben - I have tested it by accessing the site using the same credentials. I am able to access the List via URL and not via OData Connector

Comment: Let me ask the question another way: are you running the SSIS package by hand through your own account or through something like the SQL Agent where a different account is being used?

Comment: I am running the packages manually not with any scheduler

Comment: Hmm… that is interesting then. I'd still advise getting with your sharepoint admin to see if s/he has anything in their logs that might indicate what the problem is. If nothing else, it would seem that something changed and they might know what.